# C++ Thread/Vector Chat

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging

Ok what i am doing as follow, i start a constructer where the Socket is being made for the server to Listen.
(binding, listening, etc)
Then i will spawn a Thread to start a function that looks for incoming calls from clients, who he must accept.
AFter acception the Socket who connected must be placed in a list.
Afterwards a new Thread is being made.

But he stucks at the accept of clients and i really looked into it.
Hope it isnt to much to ask.

`First-chance exception at 0x010820b1 in ChatServer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x010820b1 in ChatServer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

It is a bit much->
ServerCode:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

//Constructor that takes care of making connection

//Throw in a new Thread

CreateThread(0,0,&ServerListenThread,0,0,0);

//while loop to get input and pass it to the SendMessages function

//function being called within a Thread

DWORD WINAPI ServerListenThread(LPVOID pParam)
{   
    while(1)

        CServerObj->StartListenClient();
    return 0;
}

void CServer::StartListenClient()
{

    sockaddr_in i_addr;
    int i_addrlen = sizeof(i_addr);
    SocketC = accept(SocketS,(struct sockaddr*)&i_addr,&i_addrlen);  <<<Here it gives the Access Violation< at the accept
    {
            cout << "A Connection was found with :" <<endl;
    }

    SocketS = SocketC;

    if(SocketS != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        vClientList.push_back(SocketS);
        CreateThread(0,0,&ServerRecThread, (void*)SocketS, 0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the call stack in Debug mode and post it here? You only posted information that _Inside failed, but what part of your code called this _Inside is more interesting.

Comment: A contributing factor could be the terminating condition of the for loop in CServer::SendMessages, use itl != vClientVector.end() the less-than operator is producing unpredictable results here.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely running into a scenario where you are attempting to access a value in your vector through a stale iterator.  Since you're using threads, you may have a scenario where one thread is adding to the vector, and that has caused a re-allocation of the contents of the vector.  Thus if another thread is iterating through the vector at the same time, its iterator will be invalidated after the reallocation of the original vector's contents, and you'll run into the error you're encountering where the iterator is pointing to content that is not inside the vector.

If your `vClientVector` is shared between threads, and there is a thread writing into it while other threads are reading it, then it should be protected with a mutex, probably of the reader/writer type so as to allow multiple readers, but only a single writer at a time.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, i must protect it with a Mutex.
But the thing is, it even hangs with one Client connected to it.
So if one connects i see that the `_Ptr` (debug) has the value of 128 that is the sock_identifier that needs to be stored. but the vector is empty and remains that way.

Comment: The code you've posted is very confusing ... I don't see where `_Inside` is being called from, so I'm just having to make an educated guess on what's creating this error ... In general, if you have a shared resource, and you're reading and writing to it, it should be protected.  BTW, if you create a thread, you automatically have two threads -- the parent thread, and the spawned "child" thread.  That being said, I'm still a bit confused on how your threads are interacting with each other.

Comment: well after accepting a new connection request by the server, it puts the socket that connected in the vector. Afterwards it passes the Socket to create a Thread. That Thread is only to receive data from that perticulair client.
That data is being forwarded to another function `int CServer::SendMessages(string sBuf)` that will hold the vector(with connected sockets and sends it to the sockets within.

Comment: So the vector is only written to once, and its values are only accessed by the thread that wrote into it after the writing process? In other words, in the flow of the thread, there is no point where the vector is written to after it's being read from?